# Strange error with WIF RTM, occurs after reset IIS

Tags: iis, single-sign-on, wif

I am hosting my web application on windows server 2008 with IIS 7.5, 
I have 2 web applications:
1. the first one is the core sso (Single Sign-on) service with  a login page.
2. another web application is hosted on the same web server which use the first app for sso.

I am using the WIF RTM to implementation the sso,

usually, it is running good without any problem, the user can login throw the sso and redirect back the start page.
but when I login throw the sso first, then restart the IIS, if I come back to the second application and refresh the page, I got the following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Key not valid for use in specified state. 
>   Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException:
>   Key not valid for use in specified
>   state.
>
> Source Error:  An unhandled exception
>   was generated during the execution of
>   the current web request. Information
>   regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using
>   the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [CryptographicException: Key not valid
>   for use in specified state. ]
>   System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Unprotect(Byte[]
>   encryptedData, Byte[] optionalEntropy,
>   DataProtectionScope scope) +425
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.ProtectedDataCookieTransform.Decode(Byte[]
>   encoded) +59
>
> [InvalidOperationException: ID1073: A
>   CryptographicException occurred when
>   attempting to decrypt the cookie using
>   the ProtectedData API (see inner
>   exception for details). If you are
>   using IIS 7.5, this could be due to
>   the loadUserProfile setting on the
>   Application Pool being set to false. ]
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.ProtectedDataCookieTransform.Decode(Byte[]
>   encoded) +151
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ApplyTransforms(Byte[]
>   cookie, Boolean outbound) +109
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken(XmlReader
>   reader, SecurityTokenResolver
>   tokenResolver) +634
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken(Byte[]
>   token, SecurityTokenResolver
>   tokenResolver) +105
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule.ReadSessionTokenFromCookie(Byte[]
>   sessionCookie) +239
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule.TryReadSessionTokenFromCookie(SessionSecurityToken&
>   sessionToken) +59
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object
>   sender, EventArgs eventArgs) +52
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +68    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>   +75
>
> ________________________________________ Version Information: Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version:2.0.50727.4927;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4927

the user session are stored by using SQLServer session mode, I am using a special database for this.

I have tried a lot and I cannot re-procedure this problem on my local computer (Windows7).
did anyone have similar experience? can you tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could well be because your application pool user has no persistent user profile.  To rectify this you can just run something as that user:

```
runas /user:<domain>\<user> cmd
```

And this will create the profile.  Subsequently the data should be decryptable after restarting IIS.

Comment: I didn't verify if this will solve this issue, since this has been a long time and I am absent from that project, anyone met this issue please add your comments. thx!

Answer (score 2):

I finally solve this problem by change the  application pool user to a local user.
the problem is probably caused by the sso is hosted on a 64bit OS, this problem does not exist if I host the sso on a 32bit computer (even I use a domain user for the application pool).

Now I use ApplicationPoolIdentity or NetWork Service, the exception disappeared after I restart IIS.

Thanks all you guys and I am so glad to share my solution with you.

Comment: ok, finally, I had to say, it is because of the domain user I used for the application pool does not have some required access rights, but I don't know what kind of rights. can anyone we find that also send me an email (wlmzfx@gmail.com)?

Comment: Anyone running into this please check my answer below as I think it's right.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some kind of security issue when you have several apps sharing the same domain on Win Server 2008 with IIS 7.5

If you have urls `http://ourdomain.com/app1` and `http://ourdomain.com/app2` you can sign in on one app with WIF but when you access the other app you get this error. This is because the Cookie is for the domain but if it´s created by app1 then app2 can't access it.

So the solution is to either do as Aaron and use a specific user that has access rights or as we did, separate the apps on two different domains ie `http://app1domain.com/` and `http://app2domain.com/`.

Comment: what do you mean "separate the apps on two different domains ie http://app1domain.com/ and http://app2domain.com/"? 
if I use http://app1.domain.com and http://app2.domain.com, I still have this problem.

And what kind of special access rights required if I use a domain user?

Comment: First we used one website (domain.com) with two virtual directories, app1 and app2. We had to split them into two websites with different domains (app1domain.com and app2domain.com) to get it to work. You probably need two app pools as well.

We never tested different access rights or users but since you got it to work I figured it was a valid solution.

Comment: sure, I tried to create two different pools for app1 and app2 with a domain user, but I still got the problem, If I use a domain user who is a administrator then it is the same as use ApplicationPoolUser or NetWork Service, from this, i can say that is must the domain user is missing some access rights, but I don't know what rights.